# Logging from Multiple Threads, .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I have JournalService class, which collects records coming on events. The class collects records in a list. Events come from multiple threads. There is a limit in the records list length. I'm using .NET 4.0.
To make it thread safe, I'm locking reading and writing access to "records" list.
I'm not experienced in that matter and I'm not sure I'm doing it well.
Probably I have to use [System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

My question is: Do I need to repair my code and what concurrent class to use and how?

The current code is:

```
public class JournalService : IJournalService
{
    private readonly List<JournalRecord> records = new List<JournalRecord>();
    private readonly ISettings settings;

    public JournalService(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, ISettings settings)
    {
        if (eventAggregator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("eventAggregator");
        if (settings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("settings");

        this.settings = settings;
        eventAggregator.JournalRecordPosted += EventAggregator_JournalRecordPosted;
    }

    public IEnumerable<JournalRecord> GetRecords()
    {
        JournalRecord[] tempRecords;
        lock (records)
        {
            tempRecords = records.ToArray();
        }
        return tempRecords;
    }

    private void EventAggregator_JournalRecordPosted(object sender, JournalRecordEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (records)
        {
            int surplus = records.Count - settings.TradeJournalLength;
            if (surplus == 0)
                records.RemoveAt(0);
            else if (surplus > 0)
                records.RemoveRange(0, surplus);
            records.Add(e.Record);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Surplus calculation put inside the lock.
**EDIT**: Added check for *surplus == 0*.

Comment: The surplus calculation should be done *inside* the lock. Otherwise it appears to the "Thread Safe". Unless it's a bottleneck, I don't see why it would need to be "repaired" insofar as concurrency - although the bounds of a List (when used as a FIFO) are icky as it involves a number of moves. (Maybe a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) would be better; and still not touching Concurrent :D)

Comment: Are you just trying to keep the most recent N records? For example, you want to keep just the last 100 or 1,000 records?

Comment: Jim - Yes, I need only last N records.
user2246674 - I'll put surplus in lock.

Comment: What you have will work, provided you put the surplus calculation inside the lock. The `RemoveRange` is an O(n) operation, and can cause a bottleneck if you call this a lot or have a very large number of records. You might want to look at using a circular buffer instead. There's a reasonable implementation at http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CircularBuffer/CircularBuffer.cs

Comment: I have 0-5 records per second. Journal length is about 2000 records. Once the length is reached. It removes the oldest record at every call.

Answer (score 0):

You may use 
ConcurrentQueue with lock free

```
private int _length = 0;
private void EventAggregator_JournalRecordPosted(object sender, JournalRecordEventArgs e)
{
    records.Enqueue(e.Record);


    if(Interlocked.Increment(ref _length)>=settings.TradeJournalLength)
    while(!records.Dequeue())
    {

    }
Interlocked.Decrement(ref _length)
}
```

Comment: This could use indentation and an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ConcurrentQueue:

```
private void EventAggregator_JournalRecordPosted(object sender, JournalRecordEventArgs e)
{
    records.Enqueue(e.Record);

    if (records.Count >= settings.TradeJournalLength)
    {
        recordType temp = null;
        records.TryDequeue(out temp);
    }
}
```